# How to reproduce the following effect in CSS, stuck at padding(I think) Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried everything I can think of and I cannot reproduce this form in this way:

I want to make it to look exactly like in the picture but I have the following problems:

The buttons and the last text input are not staying inline.No ideea how to fix this and possibly resize the other ones so they look like in the picture.
I cannot use specific fonts already imported into html(I've tried adding them in css with the !important function, still doesen't work)
Problems with the button color.

I really have no more ideeas left.I am very new to all this.

Can someone help me make the modifications necessary to reproduce the form in the picture?

Here is what I have now:

http://www.bootply.com/x59KVak

Comment: you just want to get rid of the fourth column or what? We do the job for you...]]>

Comment: @Frankey no lol,I didn't take the screenshot right.I have all the columns ,everything is okay.It's the Form I'm having issues with, and only CSS issues.I have updated the picture so you can see what I mean

Comment: `<div class="section">` Really? You should start using HTML5 and proper tags with some semantic meaning. Like in `<section>`.

Comment: @ feeelaI'm sorry, I'm still pretty new to webdev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User this for your last line button and text, tested it and found working

```
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label for="Camera2">Camera dorita</label>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
           <input class="form-control" id="camera" type="text">
      </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cauta</button>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ Ali Adravi you are amazing, this finnaly did it, Never thought to introduce them as a 12 grid system.Thanks.Any ideea How I can make the  rounded text input areas and button not rounded,just a normal rectangle?

Comment: @AdrianSynRusnac take a look at this for the button: http://jsfiddle.net/en6h9/2/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the two elements in a div and float them left and right: [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/GuXZ2sHoeS)

```
<div>
<input style="float:left">
<button style="float:right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add div parent for input and button and make float left,right...here is fixed, if i understand good.
http://www.bootply.com/TGuWOd5ZET